# Removing a Row with Missing Values in Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array (type `numpy.ndarray`) where a few rows have missing values (all missing values to be precise). How do I remove a row from the array if it contains missing values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.isfinite` in combination with `np.any` or `np.all` with the `axis` argument.

```
a = np.round(np.random.normal(size=(5, 3)), 1)
a[1, 2] = np.nan
a[2] = np.nan

print(a)
print(a[np.all(np.isfinite(a), axis=1)])  # Removes rows with any non-finite values.
print(a[np.any(np.isfinite(a), axis=1)])  # Removes rows that are all non-finite.
```